# ListView is not reflecting changes

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8, observablelist

I created a TableView a while back and registered Properties to each of the TableColumns. Editing of the internal data reflected itself back in the TableView just fine.

With a ListView, however, it is a different story. The changes are not being shown right away unless I close the frame and open it again.

My ListView consists of ActionSteps. Note that I used the Javafx beans properties.

```
package application.objects;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class ActionStep {

   private StringProperty actionStepID;
   private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateSet, dateFinished;
   private StringProperty stepName;
   private IntegerProperty completion;
   private ArrayList<StepComment> comments;



   public ActionStep(String name) {
      actionStepID = new SimpleStringProperty();
      stepName = new SimpleStringProperty();
      dateSet = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>();
      dateFinished = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>();
      completion = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
      stepName.setValue(name);
   }



   public void setName(String name) {
      stepName.setValue(name);
   }



   public String getName() {
      return stepName.getValue();
   }



   public StringProperty stepNameProperty() {
      return actionStepID;
   }



   public void setID(String id) {
      actionStepID.setValue(id);
   }



   public String getID() {
      return actionStepID.get();
   }



   public StringProperty actionStepIDProperty() {
      return actionStepID;
   }



   public void setCompletion(int percent) {
      if (percent < 0 || percent > 100)
         return;
      completion.set(percent);
   }



   public int getCompletion() {
      return completion.get();
   }



   public IntegerProperty completionProperty() {
      return completion;
   }



   public void setDateSet(LocalDate date) {
      dateSet.set(date);
   }



   public LocalDate getDateSet() {
      return dateSet.get();
   }



   public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateSetProperty() {
      return dateSet;
   }



   public void setDateFinished(LocalDate date) {
      dateFinished.set(date);
   }



   public LocalDate getDateFinished() {
      return dateFinished.get();
   }



   public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateFinishedProperty() {
      return dateFinished;
   }



   public String toString() {
      return stepNameProperty().get();
   }

}
```

My ListView uses an ObservableList as well.

```
  @FXML
  private ListView<ActionStep> actionStepsListView;
  private ObservableList<ActionStep> listOfSteps;

  listOfSteps = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  actionStepsListView.setItems(listOfSteps);
  if (plan != null) {
     ArrayList<ActionStep> arrayOfSteps = plan.getStepsArrayList();
     for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfSteps.size(); i++)
        listOfSteps.add(arrayOfSteps.get(i));
  } else
     plan = new ActionPlan();
```

How come changes made to the ObservableList do not reflect themselves in the ListView? I noticed that the ListView called upon every object's toString() to display their values in the ListView, rather than binding it to their Properties.

What am I doing wrong? Am I supposed to override a cell factory or something?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906139/javafx-update-of-listview-if-an-element-of-observablelist-changes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that you're trying to do something more complex with the cells in your `ListView` than you were with the cells in the `TableView`. In the `TableView`, the objects displayed in the cells were changing, so it was easy for the cells to observe this. In the `ListView`, you want the cells to notice when properties that belong to the objects displayed in the cells change; this is one further step removed, so you have to do a bit of extra coding (though not much, as you'll see).

You could create a custom cell factory to bind to the `stepNameProperty()`, but it's tricky (you have to make sure to unbind/remove listeners from old items in the `updateItem()` method).

The easier way, though, which isn't well documented is to use an `ObservableList` with an extractor defined.

First, fix your method names: you have some weird mismatches in the code you posted. The getX/setX/xProperty method names should all match correctly. I.e. instead of

```
   public void setName(String name) {
      stepName.setValue(name);
   }



   public String getName() {
      return stepName.getValue();
   }



   public StringProperty stepNameProperty() {
      return actionStepID;
   }
```

you should have

```
   public final void setName(String name) {
      stepName.setValue(name);
   }



   public final String getName() {
      return stepName.getValue();
   }


   public StringProperty nameProperty() {
      return stepName;
   }
```

and similarly for the other property accessor methods. (Obviously, the names of the fields can be anything you like, as they're private.) [Making the get/set methods final is good practice.](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/javafx-2-prog-model-1524061.pdf)

Then, [create the list with an extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-). The extractor is a function that maps each element in the list to an array of `Observable`s which the list will observe. If those values change, it will fire list updates to the list's observers. Since your `ActionStep`'s `toString()` method references the `nameProperty()`, I assume you want the `ListView` to update if the `nameProperty()` changes. So you want to do

```
  listOfSteps = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    actionStep -> new Observable[] { actionStep.nameProperty() } // the "extractor"
  );
  actionStepsListView.setItems(listOfSteps);
```

Note that in earlier versions of JavaFX 2.2 the `ListView` did not properly observe the list for update events; this was fixed (if I remember correctly) shortly prior to the release of Java 8. (Since you tagged the question JavaFX8, I assume you're using Java 8 and so you should be fine here.)

If you are not using Java 8, you can use the following (equivalent but more verbose) code:

```
listOfSteps = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    new Callback<ActionStep, Observable[]>() {
        @Override
        public Observable[] call(ActionStep actionStep) {
            return new Observable[] { actionStep.nameProperty() } ;
        }
    });
actionStepListView.setItems(listOfSteps);
```

Comment: I am indeed using Java 8 with JavaFX 8. I am also running JDK 8u5 and JRE 1.8. (I'm confused as to what all the differences are?!) I did not know of this extractor method. Does actionStep here refer to a particular ActionStep or the entire array of ActionSteps I loaded?

Comment: It's a parameter to the function, so it will be applied to each one as needed. I'll update to use an explicit inner class instead of the lambda expression, it might be clearer

Comment: I did an exact copy-paste and ended up with: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ObservableList<new Callback<ActionStep,Observable[]>(){}> to ObservableList<ActionStep>. What type is listOfSteps supposed to be ? It is current an ObservableList<ActionStep>.

Comment: Also in the lambda version:
listOfSteps = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList(actionStep-> {
                  return new Observable[] { actionStep.};
            });
How does it know that actionStep is of type ActionStep? Content assist tells me that actionStep is being treated as a POJO, so none of the methods from the ActionStep class are visible.

Comment: NEVERMIND! It turns out I had the wrong import used for Observable.

Alright, now that I have it looking like:
      listOfSteps = FXCollections.observableArrayList(step -> {
         return new Observable[] { step.stepNameProperty() };
      });

How do I give it some data? Usually the listOfSteps would use the .add() method to add items into it. But what about now?

Edit: Ah, I just add them in the list regularly with add().

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. It works now! I can only wonder why ListView isn't as intuitive with regards to Observables as TableView is. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample how make listview with custom objects:

```
public class JavaFX_ListView extends Application {

    class MyObject {
        String day;
        int number;

        MyObject(String d, int n) {
            day = d;
            number = n;
        }

        String getDay() {
            return day;
        }

        int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return number + " " + day;
        }
    }

    ObservableList<MyObject> myList;

    // Create dummy list of MyObject
    private void prepareMyList() {
        myList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        myList.add(new MyObject("Sunday", 50));
        myList.add(new MyObject("Monday", 60));
        myList.add(new MyObject("Tuesday", 20));

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("sample");
        prepareMyList();
        ListView<MyObject> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setItems(myList);

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(listView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
        // testing
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new UpdateListTask(), 1000, 1000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // testing
    public class UpdateListTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myList.add(new MyObject("sample", Calendar.getInstance()
                            .getTime().getSeconds()));
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to run a thread for updating the ListView? I want changes to be instantaneous, and since there are possibly thousands of items in the ListView, I should only update the ones that were changed, and not check the rest of them.

Comment: I use thread only for clarity - it's a normal - update ui from another thread. In my sample you can update any element in `myList`without checking rest of them.

Comment: @Tonimiko This is possible, but the more idiomatic way is to use observers and wire them up, as suggested by James_D's answer.