# JavaFX 8 + Scene Builder + Editing Cells & writing back to FXCollections.observableArrayList

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I want to do the following: Edit a cell, save the data to inside my FXCollections.observableArrayList after which the table was populated.

FXMLController:

@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert nickColumn != null : "fx:id=\"nickColumn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";
    assert groupColumn != null : "fx:id=\"groupColumn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Scene.fxml'.";

```
PlayerList playerList = new PlayerList();

playerTable.setItems(playerList.playerList);

nickColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player,String>("nick"));
nickColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

groupColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player,String>("group"));
yearOfBirthColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player,Integer>("yearOfBirth"));
ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player,Integer>("age"));
genderColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player,String>("gender"));
lastOnlineColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player,String>("lastOnline"));
```

}

---

Player.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package de.freakyonline.ucone;

import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author uwe
 */
public class Player {
    private SimpleStringProperty nick;
    private SimpleStringProperty group;
    private SimpleStringProperty gender;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty yearOfBirth;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty age;
    private SimpleStringProperty lastOnline; 


    public Player (String nick, String group, int yearOfBirth, int age, String gender, String lastOnline) {
        this.nick = new SimpleStringProperty(nick);
        this.group = new SimpleStringProperty(group);
        this.gender = new SimpleStringProperty(gender);
        this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        this.lastOnline = new SimpleStringProperty(lastOnline);
        this.yearOfBirth = new SimpleIntegerProperty(yearOfBirth);

        System.out.println("In Player Class:" + lastOnline);
    }

    public String getNick () {
        return nick.get();
    }

    public String getGroup () {
        return group.get();
    }

    public String getGender () {
        return gender.get();
    }

    public int getYearOfBirth() {
        return yearOfBirth.get();
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age.get();
    }

    public String getLastOnline() {
        return lastOnline.get();
    }

    public void setNick (String nick) {
        this.nick.set(nick);
    }

    public void setGroup (String group) {
        this.group.set(group);
    }

    public void setGender (String gender) {
        this.gender.set(gender);
    }

    public void setYearOfBirth (int yearOfBirth) {
        this.yearOfBirth.set(yearOfBirth);
    }

    public void setAge (int age) {
        this.age.set(age);
    }

    public void setLastOnline (String lastOnline) {
        this.lastOnline.set(lastOnline);
    }

}
```

---

PlayerList.java - here is the List after which everything gets populated (playerTable.setItems(playerList.playerList); in FXMLController:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package de.freakyonline.ucone;

import de.freakyonline.ucone.Player;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

/**
 *
 * @author uwe
 */
public class PlayerList {

    ObservableList<Player> playerList;

    public PlayerList() {
        getPlayersFromServer();
    }

    private void getPlayersFromServer() {
        this.playerList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Player("freakyy85","Owner",1000,1,"m", "missing..."),
        new Player("Ky3ak","Owner",1999,10,"m", "missing...")
        );
    }
}
```

---

I've set the columns to be editable in Scene Builder. I've added this to make the nicks editable:

```
nickColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

I've this to handle the event of a commit of the cells (from inside scene builder):

```
   @FXML
    void handlePlayerEditCommit(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Commit.");

    }
```

But I get this error when pressing return:

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.commitEdit(TableCell.java:349)
    at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.lambda$createTextField$615(CellUtils.java:248)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:178)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:216)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:246)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

So I need to know, what do I have to do to not get an argument type mismatch for both, PropertyValueFactory and PropertyValueFactory.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: ok by a coincidence I found something out:     @FXML
    private void handlePlayerEditCommit(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Player, String> event) {
    } would somehow work, but I got this by rightlcickin netbeaons on the  Scene.fxml and generate controller, and it generated this additional method inside the FXMLController Class. But now no table entries are shown anymore. Why doesn't scene builder show me this method in the skeleton preview. can i do it using this method? i need to find the error the generation caused now.

Comment: nm i did an undo and just replaced the other ActionEvent event method arguments by TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Player, String> . now I need to find out how to write back to the playerlist.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269932/javafx-tableview-not-binding-reverting?noredirect=1&lq=1