# ListSelectionView not displaying contents of ObservableList

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I have a ListSelectionView (from the ControlsFX library) in JavaFX and I need it to display a set of values when a particular button is clicked. It displays the values when I place the add the contents into it in the initialize method. But when I place the same code in the event action method of a button it doesn't display. I have another method which gets the Source items and Target items  from the ListSelectionView and displays them. Even though the ListSelectionView isn't displaying anything, the getSourceItems() method returns a set of values which are then displayed.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private JFXListView<Label> listv;
    @FXML
    private ListSelectionView<Label> abc;


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

    @FXML
    private void handleToggle(MouseEvent event) {

        ObservableList<Label> users = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


        abc.setSourceHeader(new Label("Present"));
           abc.setTargetHeader(new Label("Absent"));

        for (int i=0; i<4;i++)
        {
           users.add(new Label("Name "+i));
         }
        abc.setSourceItems(users);
        abc.setDisable(false);
         for (int i=0; i<4;i++)
        {
            Label k = new Label("Hello"+i);
            listv.getItems().add(k);

        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handlenewNOde(MouseEvent event) {

        ObservableList<Label> users1 =abc.getSourceItems();
       System.out.println("Source items");
       for(int i =0; i<users1.size(); i++)
       {
           Label k=users1.get(i);
           System.out.println(k.getText());
       }
       System.out.println("Target items");
       ObservableList<Label> users12 =abc.getTargetItems();

       for(int i =0; i<users12.size(); i++)
       {
           Label k=users12.get(i);
           System.out.println(k.getText());
       }
    }

}
```

.fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import org.controlsfx.control.ListSelectionView?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="680.0" prefWidth="914.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="listselectionviewtryout.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="21.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="54.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <JFXListView fx:id="listv" layoutX="131.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="237.0" prefWidth="75.0" />
      <JFXButton layoutX="413.0" layoutY="58.0" onMouseClicked="#handleToggle" text="Toggle Extension" />
      <JFXButton layoutX="445.0" layoutY="134.0" onMouseClicked="#handlenewNOde" text="new Node" />
      <ListSelectionView fx:id="abc" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="262.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Ignore the JFXListView.
Output:

```
Source items
Name 0
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Target items
```

[image]

Comment: You are using `Label` but I don't see where you set the `graphic` in the  `ListView`'s  `cellFactory`. Why not just use `String` instead of `Label`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838341/javafx-custom-cell-factory-with-custom-objects

Comment: No particular reason. Just tried it with String. No changes in the output.@SedrickJefferson

Comment: I'm not familiar with ListView's cellFactory.

Comment: I just noticed that you are working with a `ListSelectionView` lol. My suggestion was for `ListView`. Sorry

Comment: My first time using this control. I just updated my answer. It should show something now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should

```
 abc.setSourceItems(users);
```

be

```
abc.getSourceItems().addAll(users);
```

Comment: I ran your code with this change and it worked for me.

Comment: I am not sure. I read the javadoc. It said setSourceItems sets the underline model. I assumed it should work with this code.

Comment: Thanks @SedrickJefferson. I still don't get why doesn't setSourceItem() didn't work.

Comment: I don't know why either. James down voted me because I can't explain why.