# FXML ListView, I can't add my ObservableArrayList<Pane> to it

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm writing a messenger in Java and FXML and I want to show all the current chats of the user on a `ListView`(chatBar). My chats are in an `ObservableArrayList` but I still can't add the values to the `ListView`.

```
public void fillChatBar() {
    ArrayList<Chat> chats = db.getAllInvolvedChats(user.getUserID());

    ObservableList<Pane> chatHolder = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    chats.forEach(chat -> {
        Pane chatPane = new Pane();
        Label chatName = new Label();
        chatName.setText(chat.getOpponent(user.getUserID()).getUsername());
        chatPane.getChildren().add(chatName);
        chatPane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(chat.getOpponent(user.getUserID()).getProfileImage()));

        chatHolder.add(chatPane);
    });

    chatBar.setItems(chatHolder);
}
```

I get no error messages or exceptions. It just won't show.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to have an `ObservableList` of `Pane`.

Comment: I am guessing that you should be taking an approach similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838341/javafx-custom-cell-factory-with-custom-objects.

Comment: Nonetheless this should work. This means the issue seems to be some part of the program you haven't included in the question. You need to post a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you misunderstood the usage of `ListView` ;)

The `items` that are stored in a `ListView` are no `cell-views` but models. Internally the `ListView` creates cells that represents the model items and shows them on screen. You can try this by simply creating a `ListView<String>` and add a list of Strings to the items. You will see labels that shows the `String` values omg the screen. For such basic datatypes like `String` your `ListView` automatically creates cell-views to hat makes sense. For more complexe model types (like a list of custom models) you need to write your own cell-view factory (or overwrite `toString()` in your model class). See [this tutorial](https://o7planning.org/en/11063/javafx-listview-tutorial) as a first example to work with Strings. A more complexe example can be found [here](http://www.guigarage.com/2014/09/enrich-list-ui-using-medialistcell/).