# How can I store whole Objects but only display their names?

Tags: java, javafx

so the question may seem very unclear and I'm sorry but I will explain better here. I am currently working on a feature where you can ban users from an app. In the database, each user has an unique `userId` and I was thinking on banning based on that.

To ban a user from a room, I thought about adding an entry to a new table called `bannedUser`, which has 3 columns: `id` (randomly generated, primary key), `roomId` and `userId` (both foreign keys). Now each user has an username, which I display in a list of participants to the room. To do that, I have a method that gets all users in a room and returns a `List<User>`, which I then map to a `List<String>` with only the usernames. This means that I lose the `userId`. Now if I want to ban a user, I have to provide the `userId` and since usernames are not unique, I cannot search for it using just the username.

Therefore, I'm asking for help. I don't know exactly how I should do this. Let's say a moderator clicks a ban user button. This gets all users in the room and creates a pop-up with all usernames. Where and how should I store the `userId`s for each username without revealing them to the moderator?

Comment: If usernames are not unique, how will a moderator be able to tell the difference between two users with the same name, if you don't reveal the user id?

Comment: *"`List<User>`, which I then filter to a `List<String>`"* the correct term is "map", not "filter" but there lies your problem: you're mixing model and presentation. First filter out the users that should not be displayed, then map them to a list of strings.

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use ListView, in particular about custom cells

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838341/javafx-custom-cell-factory-with-custom-objects