# Refreshing individual ListView items in javafx

Tags: listview, javafx, refresh, listener

Hiho,

I have a problem with getting ListView to update "nicely". It's a playlist with a bunch of playlist items. Basically, when the style or content of an item changes, I want it to change in the ListView. Currently, I refresh the whole list, which works I guess but it seems like a really poor (unclear) solution to me (and it flickers). Is there a way to refresh/repaint a specific item? I haven't been able to find any.

For reference, each item needs to be updated when the following happens:

- The file related to the item is being read and eg it fails; or the metadata is retrieved.
- Or; from user input, eg when changing the current song.

Can I make use of a Listener somehow? I've looked at bindings etc but I don't seem to find what I'm looking for. Any help greatly appreciated

Edited again: Working code below

Initialise the list:

```
protected Playlist(List<PlaylistItem> list){
    ...

    // initialise the items
    backup = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
    setItems(backup);

    // Use a custom CellFactory
    setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<PlaylistItem>, ListCell<PlaylistItem>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<PlaylistItem> call(ListView<PlaylistItem> list) {
            return new PlaylistCell();
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

The cells created by the factory:

```
private class PlaylistCell extends ListCell<PlaylistItem> {
    private PlaylistItem lastItem = null;
    private final BooleanProperty booleanProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    /** Add a listener to the boolean property upon construction */
    private PlaylistCell() {
        booleanProperty.addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if (newValue) { updateItem(lastItem, lastItem == null); };
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(PlaylistItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        booleanProperty.set(false);

        if (lastItem != item){
            // remove the pointer if we change item
            if (lastItem != null && booleanProperty == lastItem.getBooleanProperty())
                lastItem.setBooleanProperty(null);
            // and attach it to the new item
            if (item != null)
                item.setBooleanProperty(booleanProperty);
        }

        // redraw the cell
        if (!empty && item != null) {
            lastItem = item;

            // current song in bold
            if (item.equals(current)) {
                setId("current-item");
            } else{
                setId(null);
            }

            // mark queued songs & update text
            if (queue.contains(item)) {
                int i = queue.indexOf(item);
                super.setText(item.toString() + "\t (" + (i + 1) + (i != queue.lastIndexOf(item) ? ", ...)": ')'));
            } else {
                super.setText(item.toString());
            }
        }

        // draw an empty cell
        else {
            lastItem = null;
            setText(null);
            setId(null);
        }

    }

}
```

And then when I eg double-click an item it's to current or when I queue an item, I set the BooleanProperty to true (ie has changed) to trigger the update call.

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you are doing? Specifically, if the items in the list use [JavaFX properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) you can just do this by specifying a list with an [extractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822550/listview-is-not-reflecting-changes).

Comment: James_D: Added some code. I tried using a StringProperty quickly but it seemed overly complicated for something so simple since, as far as I understood, I would need one listener for each item. I'll look at extractors a bit either way because I am also able to search through the list. Thanks

Comment: There's not really enough code there to understand what you are doing. But, as I said, you should use an `ObservableList` with an extractor (see link to API docs in previous comment). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822550/listview-is-not-reflecting-changes

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up tying a BooleanProperty (java fx bean?) with a ChangeListener to each CellFactory, and each CellFactory to the current item being displayed. Then I made any changes to the Item modify the bean property and updates fire that way. A bit cumbersome but at least I don't have a bunch of CellFactories waiting to be garbage collected (I think :D)

I'll probably have to implement an extractor for searching though

Comment: I think you have some major misunderstandings about how this works. There is only one cell factory for the entire list view, and cells (which you represent by a class called `CellFactory`, for some bizarre reason) exist essentially only for the visible cells. So I don't understand what the memory management concerns are - I think you are creating issues that don't exist. If you use an extractor on your list, then the cell's `updateItem(...)` method gets invoked when the property changes, so I don't understand why you would create extra properties specifically for the cell.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you are right. I was thinking that was very odd. I updated the code again now. So, what I meant I have done is: tie a BooleanProperty with a listener to each Cell and attach it to the item it is displaying. When an item changes and it has a BooleanProperty attached, I set that property to true and the listener fires the updateItem();. I.e., for each visible cell, there's a property and a listener. I wasn't sure how to detect "changes" in another way without heaps of pointers. Thanks a lot for your patience btw. I'll look into Extractors until next time I fiddle with this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `queue` is an `ObservableList<PlaylistItem>` of items in a queue to be played, and `current` is an `ObjectProperty<PlaylistItem>` (or something similar) representing the currently playing item, I think you just need something like

```
private class PlaylistCell extends ListCell<PlaylistItem> {

    public PlaylistCell() {

        textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(this::calculateText,
            itemProperty(), emptyProperty(), current, queue);
        idProperty().bind(Bindings
            .when(current.isEqualTo(itemProperty())
            .then("current-item")
            .otherwise(""));
    }

    private String calculateText() {
        if (isEmpty() || getItem() == null) return null ;

        PlaylistItem item = getItem();

        if (queue.contains(item)) {
            int index = queue.indexOf(item) ;
            boolean unique = index == queue.lastIndexOf(item);
            return String.format("%s (%d%s)", item ,index + 1, (unique ? "" : ", ..."));
        } else {
            return item.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd recommend using a CSS [`PseudoClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) instead of manipulating the id:

```
private class PlaylistCell extends ListCell<PlaylistItem> {

    private final BooleanBinding isCurrent = current.isEqualTo(itemProperty());
    private final PseudoClass currentPC = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("current");

    public PlaylistCell() {

        textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(this::calculateText,
            itemProperty(), emptyProperty(), current, queue);
        isCurrent.addListener((obs, wasCurrent, isNowCurrent) -> 
            pseudoClassStateChanged(currentPC, isNowCurrent));
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then change the CSS to use the selector

```css
.list-cell:current { /* ... */ }
```

instead of

```css
#current-item { /* ... *. }
```

As an alternative to creating the bindings, you could also create your data list with an [extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822550/listview-is-not-reflecting-changes), which will cause the usual `updateItem()` method to be invoked when either the currently playing item, or the queue, change:

```
ObservableList<PlaylistItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    item -> new Observable[] { current, queue /* , other properties the toString() depends on...*/ });

ListView<PlaylistItem> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.setItems(items);
```

and then

```
public class PlaylistCell extends ListCell<PlayListItem> {

    private final PseudoClass currentPC = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("current");


    @Override
    protected void updateItem(PlaylistItem item, boolean empty) {

        pseudoClassStateChanged(currentPC, current.isEqualTo(item));

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            if (queue.contains(item)) {
                int index = queue.indexOf(item) ;
                boolean unique = index == queue.lastIndexOf(item);
                return String.format("%s (%d%s)", item ,index + 1, (unique ? "" : ", ..."));
            } else {
                return item.toString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```