# JavaFX Choiceox change not updating graphics

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

When I change the underlying observable array list the graphics choice box doesn't update. There must be a newer solution than what I have seen suggested here for example: 
[JavaFX: Update of ListView if an element of ObservableList changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906139/javafx-update-of-listview-if-an-element-of-observablelist-changes)

```
    int selected = productsChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    Product prod = products.get(selected);
    prod.setName(productName.getText());
    prod.setUrl(productUrl.getText());
```

Any thoughts? I would like to avoid removing and adding.

Comment: Sure, done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "standard" answer is to use an `ObservableList` with an `extractor`.  However, when I tested this out, it didn't behave as advertised, and it seems like there is a bug (my guess is that `ChoiceBox` is not correctly handling `wasUpdated` type changes fired in its `ListChangedListener`) which I will report at JIRA. **Update:** filed report at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38394

The factory method [`FXCollections.observableArrayList(Callback)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-) creates an (empty) observable array list. The provided `Callback` is a function that maps each element in the list to an array of `Observable`s. The list registers listeners with those observables, and if those properties change, the list fires update notifications to its listeners.

This produces strange results with a `ChoiceBox`, however; one possible workaround would be to use a `ComboBox` which seems to work fine.

Here's some sample code. Select an item: then type in the text field and press enter to change the name of the selected item. Change `ChoiceBox` to `ComboBox` to see the correct behavior:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChoiceBoxUpdateExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ChoiceBox<Item> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
        ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                item -> new Observable[] {item.nameProperty()}); // the extractor
        items.addAll(
                IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        choiceBox.setItems(items);

        TextField changeSelectedField = new TextField();
        changeSelectedField.disableProperty()
            .bind(Bindings.isNull(choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()));
        changeSelectedField.setOnAction(event -> 
            choiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setName(changeSelectedField.getText()));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(choiceBox);
        root.setBottom(changeSelectedField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Item {
        public final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name ;
        }
        public final String getName() {
            return nameProperty().get();
        }
        public final void setName(String name) {
            nameProperty().set(name);
        }
        public Item(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that is also a good point. Definitely not elegant, I just want people to know it does work, but I agree, NOT the desired choice.

Answer (score 2):

The correct and proper answer is from James_D, but if you REALLY want to use ChoiceBox, then try adding and removing:

```
    int selected = productsChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    products.remove(selected);
    products.add(selected, prod);
```

I do NOT believe this is the right way, but I tested it, and it does work. The ChoiceBox stays on the the removed and selected index and looks like it updates.