# Javafx right click edit listView item and similar methods

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a JavaFX todo list and am not sure how to continue. The right click popup menu works fine but I am not sure how to edit/change the contents of the `ListView` other than just removing them.

```
LocalEvent e = a string somehow?
```

I am trying to do 4 total things in a right click popup menu in Javafx:

1. Done is to place a check mark next to and strikeout the item.
2. Nest is to create a nested list from a list item (no idea at all how).
3. Edit is to make the list item editable and save the chages.
4. Remove works :)

I have done this by adding the following to the fxml file:

`<JFXListView fx:id="eventList" editable="true" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="354.0" prefWidth="939.0">`

```
<contextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
          <items>
            <MenuItem fx:id="popUp" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Done" text="Done" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="popUp3" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Remove" text="Remove" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="popUp1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Nest" text="Nest" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="popUp2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Edit" text="Edit" />
          </items>
        </ContextMenu>
     </contextMenu></JFXListView>`
```

Here is my Controller.java file:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        eventList.setExpanded(true);
        eventList.depthProperty().set(1);   
    }

    @FXML
    private MenuItem popUp;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField textBox;

    @FXML
    private JFXListView<LocalEvent> eventList;
    ObservableList<LocalEvent> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private JFXButton AddButton;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker datePicker;


    @FXML
    void Submit(ActionEvent event) {
        list.add(new LocalEvent(datePicker.getValue(), textBox.getText()));
        eventList.setItems(list);
        datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        textBox.setText("");

    }

    @FXML
    public void onEnter(ActionEvent event){
        list.add(new LocalEvent(datePicker.getValue(), textBox.getText()));
        eventList.setItems(list);
        datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        textBox.setText("");    
    }

    @FXML
    void Done(ActionEvent event) {
        int index = eventList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        String str = list.get(index).toString();
        str = "[✓] " +  str;
        LocalEvent e = null;    // <- how to put a string in here?
        list.set(index, e);
        eventList.setItems(list);
        //eventList.setItems(list.set(index, element));
    }

    @FXML 
    void Remove(ActionEvent event) {
        // remove selected task
        list.remove(eventList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    }

    @FXML
    void Nest(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("How the hell do I do that? lol");
        // check for nested level
        // create a nested list item

    }

    @FXML
    void Edit(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Edit selection");
        eventList.setEditable(true);
        int index = eventList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); 
        eventList.scrollTo(index);
        eventList.layout();
        eventList.edit(index); 
        eventList.layout();
    }
}
```

`LocalEvent` is a java class file as follows:

```
package application;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class LocalEvent implements ObservableList<LocalEvent> {
    private String description;
    private LocalDate date;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public LocalEvent(LocalDate date, String description) {
        this.setDate(date);
        this.setDescription(description);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "At " + this.getDate() + ": " + this.getDescription();
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<LocalEvent> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean add(LocalEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends LocalEvent> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends LocalEvent> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public LocalEvent get(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public LocalEvent set(int index, LocalEvent element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void add(int index, LocalEvent element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public LocalEvent remove(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public ListIterator<LocalEvent> listIterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public ListIterator<LocalEvent> listIterator(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public List<LocalEvent> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void addListener(ListChangeListener<? super LocalEvent> listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void removeListener(ListChangeListener<? super LocalEvent> listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(LocalEvent... elements) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean setAll(LocalEvent... elements) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean setAll(Collection<? extends LocalEvent> col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(LocalEvent... elements) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(LocalEvent... elements) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void remove(int from, int to) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Any help at all appreciated.

Comment: What is LocalEvent? I don't see it in the API.

Comment: Updated my question to have LocalEvent in it

Comment: Why would you create a class implementing `ObservableList` and then create an `ObservableList` of that class? `LocalEvent` shouldn't implement that, and all the `setItems()` can be removed as long you have done that once in the `initialize()` method, which you probably don't have at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that stands out was mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504908/javafx-right-click-edit-listview-item-and-similar-methods#comment89988326_51504908): your `LocalEvent` shouldn't implements `ObservableList`, it's just a data holder. You probably will want it to also hold a `boolean` to see if it's completed:

```
public class LocalEvent {

    private String description;
    private LocalDate date;
    private boolean completed = false;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
        this.completed= completed;
    }

    public LocalEvent(LocalDate date, String description) {
        this.setDate(date);
        this.setDescription(description);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String base = "At " + this.getDate() + ": " + this.getDescription();
        return completed ? "[✓] " + base : base;
    }
}
```

I don't know what the `jfoenix` controls are, but I'll assume they are close enough to JavaFX standard controls. The `ListView` should be bound to the list of events:

```
ObservableList<LocalEvent> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ListView<LocalEvent> eventList = new ListView<>(list);
```

(I would also rename the lists to something that makes more sense.)

Now any change to `list` will be reflected in `eventList` so you don't need to touch `eventList`. This allows your `done` method to look like:

```
@FXML
void done(ActionEvent event) {
    int index = eventList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    LocalEvent localEvent = list.get(index);
    localEvent.setCompleted(true);
    list.set(index, localEvent);
}
```

Note that we needed to reset the item in the list because it doesn't know that a field of the `LocalEvent` instance has changed. You can make it that the fields also report changes by using an extractor, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906139/javafx-update-of-listview-if-an-element-of-observablelist-changes) and many other answers here about it.

Editing depends on the cell used by the `ListView`, I would suggest reading about it in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) and other questions here. Note that you probably want to be able to edit the description and date separately and not the whole `toString` value, so you'll have to provide a mechanism for that like bringing back the `DatePicker`.

Nesting depends on what you want it to look like. You might need to define your own cell factory, but consider just adding an indentation, via `"\t"`s, which will make it looks nested. If you really need a nesting in the data model, then each `LocalEvent` will have to hold its own `ObservableList<LocalEvent> nestedEvents`.

Also, method names should start with a lowercase.