# How can I access controls of a JavaFX window from another JavaFX window?

Tags: java, javafx

How can I access a tableview's methods, such as refresh, from a different window?

Comment: This problem isn't really about "modal" windows; it is about how a changes to a model are received and processed by a view. Perhaps there is a missing listener registration? Or there is a missing event fire on the change?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906139/javafx-update-of-listview-if-an-element-of-observablelist-changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need something similar to the following steps:

- Call to open the modal view and pass your tableview and whatever you need of other values to it.
- Init tableView to a local tableview vaiable in the modal view (controller)
- Create a method in modal view controller that will update the tableview when an event happened (like save button clicked).

You need to take a look on [how to pass the values and items between different controllers in JavaFX](https://jagar.me/post/passingdatainjavafx/#sending-values-back-and-updating-the-items-on-the-layout1-ui)